# If you had the chance to give your past self advice for your thesis, what would they be?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, thesis, masters, advisor

As mentioned in the title, when you look back on your master thesis- the one that brought you to your Phd life, which advice that you think if you had known them before, you would have had a better thesis and a more promising academic career?

I think those advice would vary from advice on relationship with advisors, work-life balance to something more specific like "Do not get carried away too much by the premature results that you come up with" -which may not be true for everyone.

I expect to learn the most from you, more about your failure and how you cope with them than your success.

Sincerely,

Comment: Unfortunately, this is probably too broad for this site.

Comment: @GoodDeeds: Oh. Thank you for your comment. It's kinda sad knowing that. Nonetheless, would you mind sharing something?

Comment: This site is for *specific* Q&A. It's not good for poll/discussion/share-your-experience topics, which this seems to be.

Comment: Interesting question, but this is probably better for reddit or somewhere. You may wish to check out our [tour]; we only do Q&A as Bryan said.